# How to visualize gmapping progress on rviz?

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I managed to run gmapping to build a map from logged data. progress is going on for an hour. sequences i followed

$roscore
$rosparam set use_sim_time true
$rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=base_scan
$rosbag play

Is there any way I can visualize progressing map real time?

best regards
Hossain

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/80736/how-to-visualize-gmapping-progress-on-rviz?/) by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2013-09-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In rviz, you should be able to add a map display on the left of the screen. Then set the topic to /map which is the default from gmapping. YOu might then need to set the 'fixed frame' to /map as well at the top left of rviz.

rviz shouldn't care that you are using a bagfile vs realtime topic data stream. :)

---

Originally posted by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) with karma: 1070 on 2013-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on 2013-10-02**:
Thanks a lot Dereck. It worked.

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-10-02**:
I'm glad! It would be cool if you could mark the answer as correct by clicking the checkmark to the left. :)